# How do I print the contents of a struct in C?

Tags: c, struct, printf, average

**Resolved the issues on my own, using different methods than those suggested below! :)**

Thanks for viewing my question! :)

I've been learning about structs and working on a practice lab in C, and my code does not seem to be compiling correctly with any change I make to it. *Currently I am not receiving any output and the program crashes.* I'm still very confused on how to correctly utilize the '*' and '&' symbols when passing them into functions as well. My goals for this practice are to:

- print the contents of the array in the same format as the data file
- print the full name of the student with the best GPA
- calculate and print the average GPA
- print the names of all students with GPAs above the average
- print the name of the youngest student who has a GPA below average
- sort the structures in the array into order from lowest to highest
  GPA
- print the array again (will now be in a different order from last
  time)

**How do I properly call to and print these items from the student struct? And how would I access the gpa values to pass into a function that would calculate the average?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// define constants
#define ARR 100
#define FIRST 7
#define MIDINIT 1
#define LAST 9
#define STREET 16
#define CITY 11
#define STATE 2
#define ZIP 5
#define AGE 3
#define GPA 4
#define START 0
#define FIRSTID 8
#define INITID 10
#define STREETID 20
#define CITYID 37
#define STATEID 49
#define ZIPID 52
#define AGEID 57
#define GPAID 64

// defined structs

typedef struct {
    char street[STREET + 1];
    char city[CITY + 1];
    char state[STATE + 1];
    char zip[ZIP + 1];  
} Address;

typedef struct {
    char firstname[FIRST + 1];
    char initial[MIDINIT + 1];
    char lastname[LAST + 1];
    Address ofstudent;
    int age;
    double gpa;
} Student;

// function prototype
void strsub(char buf[], char s[], int start, int size); 
void processStudent(int *id, Student students[]);
void sortStudentGpa(Student *students, int id); 
void maxGpa(Student *students, int id);

/* lab6student.c: creates an array of student structures and outputs reports */
int main(void)
{
    Student students[ARR]; // creates an array of student structures
    int id = 0; // counter for student

    processStudent(&id, students);
    maxGpa(students, id);
}
void strsub(char buf[], char s[], int start, int size) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < size && buf[start + i] != '\0'; i++) { 
        // loops as long as iterator is less than size 
        // and while string has not run out of characters
        s[i] = buf[i + start];
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
}
/* void sort(Student *students, int id) {
    int j, i;

    for(i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < id - i; j++) {
            if(students[j].gpa > students[j + 1].gpa) {
                Student temp = students[j];
                students[j] = students[j + 1];
                students[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
} */
void processStudent(int *id, Student students[]) {
    FILE *data;
    char line[ARR];
    *id = 0; // counter for student

    data = fopen("Students.dat", "r");
    if (data == NULL) {
        printf("Students.dat file not found!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // process file
    while (!feof(data)) {
        // organize student info into separate arrays
        fgets(line, ARR, data);
        strsub(line, students[*id].firstname, START, FIRST); 
        strsub(line, students[*id].initial, FIRSTID, MIDINIT);
        strsub(line, students[*id].lastname, INITID, LAST);
        strsub(line, students[*id].ofstudent.street, STREETID, STREET);
        strsub(line, students[*id].ofstudent.city, CITYID, CITY);
        strsub(line, students[*id].ofstudent.state, STATEID, STATE);
        strsub(line, students[*id].ofstudent.zip, ZIPID, ZIP);
        students[*id].age = atoi(&line[AGEID]);
        students[*id].gpa = atoi(&line[GPAID]);
        (*id)++;
    }   

    fclose(data);
}
//sorts struct student array containing num (gpa) elements into
//ascending order
void sortStudentGpa(Student *students, int id) {
    int i, j; // indexes into unsorted and sorted partitions
    Student temp; // temporarily holds an element from the array

    for (i = 1; i < id; ++i) {
        temp = students[i];
        j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && temp.gpa < students[j].gpa) {
            students[j + 1] = students[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        students[j + 1] = temp;
    }
} 
void maxGpa(Student *students, int id) {
    int iwithmax, i;
    float max = 0;

    for ( i = 0 ; i < id ; i++) {
        if (students -> gpa > max) {
            max = students -> gpa;
            iwithmax = i;
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nHighest GPA is done by Student %d with GPA = %f", iwithmax, max);
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. Compile with warnings enabled. I find it highly unlikely that there is a compiler bug (`my code does not seem to be compiling correctly`). Start over and incrementally add back parts of your code to see where the error lies. Someone on your campus may be willing to dig through your code and debug it, Stackoverflow isn't.

Comment: Please don't ask two questions in one. How this is ever going to help other people that search SO?

Comment: In the process student function you are assigning the address for id as 0. so you have to assign the value not the address. *id = 0; Then you execute the code.

Comment: @remyabel Oh it's not that I think that my code should be working! I am using a debugger and I know my code is incorrect, but I can't decipher the error messages as they are so vague; whenever I conduct a search on it it comes up unsuccessful. And I am actually studying completely online and on my own, so I do not have anyone from a school "campus" to help me. Thanks though. :)

Answer (score 6):

In the maxGpa function just change the definition as

```
        void maxGpa(Student *students, int id);
```

then in the maxGpa function do the following changes

```
   void maxGpa(Student *students, int id) {
    int iwithmax, i;
    float max = 0;

    for ( i = 0 ; i < id ; i++) {
            if (students -> gpa > max) {
                    max = students -> gpa;
                    iwithmax = i;
            }
    }
```

Try this.....

Comment: You may want to explain when you use the `->` arrow operator, and the `.` operator with structures to make sure that learning has occurred.

Comment: while passing we will pass the address only, so we will get the pointer, so we have to use the ->. if we want to use the * then we have specify like this (*students).gpa because precedence of structure member operator . is higher than *. if we give *students.gpa it will mean *(students.gpa), this will be illegal.

Comment: This is not really a good answer. First, it only addresses the second, suplementary question that is asked at the end, not the one in the title. Then, please don't give out code snippets without an explanation.

Comment: @sharon The program compiled without error this time, but now my output looks like this: Highest GPA is done by Student 1980574048 with GPA = 0.000000